# Pulling debtor credit report without SSN

Tags: nevada

I have a judgment against a debtor with only their name and date of birth. How do I obtain their credit report? Just write to Experian with a court order?

First question- is it legal to do this. Second question- do I need their ssn, and if so, how can I legally obtain it.

Comment: Do you have the debtors permission to access their credit report?  Does the court judgement cover accessing a credit report or is it just a judgement confirming the debt and ordering repayment? If you don’t have permission from either the court or the debtor, then you won’t get anything from Experian.

Comment: I have written permission from the debtor (which the debtor denies) but have not tried court order.

Comment: If you can convince the court as to why such an invasion of privacy would help you collect on the debt, then a court would probably issue an order - but they won’t just give you one because you want the report.

Comment: It would help me find their addresses and any paid off loans on sizable assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you do this by retaining a private investigator, or by retaining a debt collection agency (which will add your debt to the debtor's credit report).

Post-judgment debtor's interrogatories posted by a judgment creditor to a judgment debtor can require the judgment debtor to reveal his SSN or the equivalent (e.g. an EIN or TIN).

It isn't clear why you would want their credit report, however. You have established that they owe you money and aren't deciding whether to extend credit which is what a credit report is used to do. A credit report does not identify the assets of a debtor, only their debts. This can be of a little help in the case of secured debt with assets of the debtor as collateral, but there are other public records that can be used to search the secured debt of a debtor (mostly real property records and Uniform Commercial Code records).

Comment: It does identify paid off loans on assets suggesting they own them. And it gives all information  on addresses, contact info etc.

Comment: Hiring a private investigator to do a quick asset search and, if necessary, a skip trace, would be more accurate and comprehensive, and usually isn't very expensive for a decent sized debt. Debtor's interrogatories can also generate this information.

Comment: PI probably wants the credit report anyway. But ok.

Comment: PI's have lots of asset search databases and directory databases and voter registration, etc by subscription that covers public real estate and UCC records that provide everything you want out of the credit report. They are also familiar with when someone is and is not authorized to get a credit report lawfully and often are allowed access under broader circumstances than members of the general public.

Comment: I can't imagine them finding a car loan. How would they find cars that aren't in the driveway?

Comment: @user30113 Car loans and car title are a matter of public record at the state level. It is one of the things that PIs routinely check.

Comment: Interesting, I thought titles were private